# Is this an okay way to allow a user to exit a program or run it again in Python?

Tags: python, exit, python-2.x

```
def exitProgram():  
    #This function gives the user the choice of exiting the program or running 
    #it again.  

    quitProgram = str(raw_input("Would you like to exit the program (y,n)"))  

    while quitProgram != "y" and quitProgram != "n":  
        quitProgram = str(raw_input("Type 'y' to quit and 'n' to run again."))  

    return quitProgram
```

Comment: Your function name exitProgram sounds like it does nothing but simply exiting the program. However it does a whole lot more, better rename it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [sys.exit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit) module

```
import sys

def exit_func():

    quitProgram = str(raw_input("Would you like to exit the program (y,n)"))

    while quitProgram != "y" and quitProgram != "n":  
        quitProgram = str(raw_input("Type 'y' to quit and 'n' to run again."))


    if quitProgram == "y":
        print "Exit program"
        sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try break:

```
def exitProgram():
    x = input("Do you want to quit?(Y/N):\n>")
    return x

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        #body

        if exitProgram() == "Y":
            break

    print("BYE!")
```